# Jquery validate form digits only

Tags: jquery, validation

I want to validate a form of mine, using the jquery validation plugin, but it has a lot of fields and I want them all to be digits. Is there a shorter way than

```
rules: {
field1: { digits},
field2: { digits},
field3: { digits},
field4: { digits},
field5: { digits}
```

Comment: See this: http://jqueryvalidation.org/digits-method/

Answer (score 3):

Could be done like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/mBRFW/

```
var rules = {};

$('input.digits').each(function () {
    rules[this.id] = {digits:true};
});

$("#myform").validate({
    rules: rules
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)

> **rules:** Key/value pairs defining custom rules. Key is the name of an element...

I don't see a way to use a class/attribute etc. instead.